# How can an accepted answer be deleted with a bounty received?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

There's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31199419/4698026) which cannot be solved as the author of the software said himself in the mailing list that the feature asked by the question cannot be provided.

I turned it into an answer to bring it into the question maker's notice, and he accepted the answer. But then a moderator came and deleted the answer. So, the question is still there which **had** the correct answer but it was deleted. How is that justified?

*Disclaimer: I have no problems discussing this matter publicly even if it involves a personal matter.*

Comment: _"I have no problems discussing this matter publicly even if it involves personal matter."_ Huh?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In one of my previous questions here, I was asked by a moderator whether I am okay discussing any own answer/question/reputation. That's why I thought I should mention it

Comment: Hmmm,, that was the same moderator? I actually cannot spot anything wrong with you answer, and why it needed to be deleted. Maybe @animuson Might want to give a more detailed explanation of their decision here.

Comment: No that was not the same mod. I tried to 'undelete' it by it says "A moderator has deleted the answer and it cannot be undeleted"

Comment: Yes please @animuson. Please provide an explanation for this decision. You didn't do it while deleting which usually should be done.

Comment: The answer at the moment just reads as your assertion that something was said in a mailing list. Can you link to where it was said? or provide a quotation? Comments are transient and your answer needs to standalone.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  That's a very good point, but I wouldn't imagine that deletion of the question would be warranted.  Downvote and comment yes, but *deletion*...

Comment: @Makoto it was probably flagged as not an answer given that the entirety of the text was `As said in the mailing list, Eclim doesn't currently support having the daemon running on a different machine/vm than the client (vim).`

Comment: @MartinSmith It wasn't flagged. This was just one moderator who deleted the answer without any explanation. Simple as that.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra: how do you know it wasn't flagged? Mod deletes like this one usually come from flags.

Comment: @MartinSmith still, not an answer means that it didn't even try to answer the question. This was an answer. A bad one, but still.

Comment: @Theolodis: Looks like an answer (now), the question is "is it possible" and the answer is "no it is not possible" with a link to the mailing-list substantiating and a quote. Is there anything else you wish for?

Comment: I can think of additional information that would *improve* the answer -- why this is not possible, what would have to change to make it possible, whether this is is something the authors would like to support in the future, that sort of thing -- but that would all have to come from  Van Dewoestine or someone similarly informed.  I don't see anything delete-worthy in the answer as is.  However, it is my personal opinion that both the moderators and the hivemind are much too trigger-happy about deleting both questions and answers.

Comment: So, given that a whole raft of your answers where deleted in a sweep at the same time (?) as this answer, is there a good reason you omitted mentioning the other deleted answers here?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm not the moderator who acted on this, but I had a chance to review what happened here. That answer was deleted as part of a larger investigation into suspicious activity involving your account. For the benefit of the Meta crowd, this was all presented to you via a private moderator message yesterday.

There was clear evidence that you used a sock puppet account, then an account by a friend, to coordinate votes for your answers. You did this in a couple of places in order to snipe automatically-awarded bounties by swooping in with an answer that these two accounts gave two upvotes for (thus satisfying the conditions of the automatic bounty award).

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31185432/19679) was directly plagiarized from two others, and you used it to get half of a 100-point bounty. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31195064/19679) was copied from the comments and artificially upvoted in order to receive the automatic bounty.

Therefore, when a moderator saw [the original form](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31366250/revisions) of the above answer and the bounty award, it fit the pattern of these other bounty abuses. It was only after it was deleted that this answer was edited into shape.

Now that the answer has been edited, and given the fact that this bounty was not scammed like the others, I've undeleted it. I should note that none of this would have happened had you not tried to take advantage of the system in your other answers.

Comment: Well, someone else edited it into shape. But it wasn't violating any quality standards in its original state, even if it was a really poor answer for a bounty. Still, the point is that an answer doesn't have to be *not an answer* or *very low quality* to be deleted by a moderator. There are *many* other reasons for a post to be mod-deleted that have nothing to do with content quality.

Comment: I think I have cleared about the "suspicious" activity of the account in the private mail and apologized where necessary. However you should not judge an answer by its author but rather by its content. Now the point is, would it have been deleted if instead of me, *someone else* had written it.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra - the point was that it checked while investigating suspicious activity on *your account*. So, yes, if someone else had written it it wouldn't have been found, but if **they'd** been engaging in suspicious activity it **would** have been found.

Comment: "However you should not judge an answer by its author but rather by its content." Which is why you shouldn't have coordinated votes on your own answers in the first place. The answers were deleted because they had scammed bounties, which cannot be as easily invalidated as votes. I imagine, though I can't say for sure, that if moderators had a way of removing bounties after they had been awarded and the answers stood on their own we might have done things a little differently.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra My interpretation of what you are saying: "I was trying to cheat my way into bounties.  In one of the cases that matched the ways I was trying to cheat the answer was borderline.  Injustice!".  Is that in essence correct?  I bring it up because *"I have no problems discussing this matter publicly even if it involves personal matter."*, and understanding context is important.  Does that reflect the situation?

Comment: Reminder that you'd have to explain this sort of event less often if high-trust users could see deleted answers on a user profile.

Comment: @zwol: We know. It sucks.

Comment: regardless of this question. Can the author of an answer who has received bounty delete their answer?